# How to add a custom framework to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" with cordova?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, swift-custom-framework

I'm including a custom framework in my Cordova plugin. I already can include manually on Xcode but I would like to include automatically after run: `cordova platform add ios`

my current plugin.xml is :

```xml
    <source src="src/ios/Betkicks.framework" target-dir="Frameworks"/>
    <source src="src/ios/Betkicks.framework" target-dir="lib" framework="true"/>
    <framework src="src/ios/Betkicks.framework" target-dir="$(SRCROOT)" embed="true" custom="true" />
```

So far I could include with success in the **"embedded binaries"** section but I have no idea how to include in the **"Linked Frameworks and Libraries"** section as you can see in the picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Ae9.png)